# Intellij Structurally replace `thows OneException, TwoException` with only Exception

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, structural-search

With [IntelliJ's s Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html) I want to replace the following snippet:

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {}
```

with:

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {}
```

The goal is to simplify tests a bit.  How do I configure the text constraints to do the replacement?

[image: IntelliJ Structural Replace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add the @Test annotation to the template too. The search template then becomes:

```
@Test
$ReturnType$ $Method$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) throws $ExceptionType$;
```

Replace template:

```
@Test
$ReturnType$ $Method$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) throws Exception;
```

Constraints:

`$Parameter$` min/max `[0,unlimited]`
`$ExceptionType$` min/max `[0,unlimited]`